# How to create a mask for specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to create a mask for my project. It is going to be for IBAN Number which looks like `EU____________` (26 Characters limitation)

How can i do this on Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for, but maybe a [check constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints) is a good solution.

Comment: i will try. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of this column? Is it just for reporting? An application?

Comment: actually i need an input mask... when user insert his/her iban number, it should looks like this --> 'EU__________________'

User should fill only the blank field.

Comment: Then on the insert statement, use `CONCAT('EU',iban number)`